# Can't Connect to MariaDB RDS instance in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I built a VPC with a few AWS resources inside of it. I can get Internet access if I'm in the VPC and resources inside the VPC can communicate with each other. For instance, I have a Lambda function that can communicate to the Internet and also reach an RDS instance inside the VPC. However, the issue comes in when I am trying to connect to the RDS instance from my local machine.

I've tried updating the VPCSecurityGroup to allow all incoming traffic, but still won't work. The only thing that seems to work is if I switch all of the Route Tables to use an IGW as opposed to a NAT, but I'd prefer if that wasn't the case. Also, I'm not even sure I'd be allowed to do that because I'm pretty sure lambda functions have to exist in private subnets.

vpc.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: VPC Stack
Resources:
  Vpc:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default    
  InternetGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'
  VpcGatewayAttachment:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  ElasticIP:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  NatGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'
    DependsOn:
      - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt 
        - ElasticIP
        - AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAPublic
  SubnetAPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select 
        - '0'
        - !GetAZs ''
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/19
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SubnetBPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select 
        - '1'
        - !GetAZs ''
      CidrBlock: 10.0.32.0/19
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SubnetAPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select 
        - '0'
        - !GetAZs ''
      CidrBlock: 10.0.64.0/19
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SubnetBPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select 
        - '1'
        - !GetAZs ''
      CidrBlock: 10.0.96.0/19
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  RouteTableAPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  RouteTableBPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  RouteTableAPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  RouteTableBPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  RouteTableAssociationAPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAPublic
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableAPublic
  RouteTableAssociationBPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetBPublic
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableBPublic
  RouteTableAssociationAPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAPrivate
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableAPrivate
  RouteTableAssociationBPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetBPrivate
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableBPrivate
  RouteTableAPrivateInternetRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    DependsOn:
      - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableAPrivate
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway
  RouteTableBPrivateInternetRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    DependsOn:
      - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableBPrivate
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway
  RouteTableAPublicInternetRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableAPublic
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  RouteTableBPublicInternetRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableBPublic
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  NetworkAclPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  NetworkAclPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociationAPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAPublic
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPublic
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociationBPublic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetBPublic
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPublic
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociationAPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAPrivate
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPrivate
  SubnetNetworkAclAssociationBPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetBPrivate
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPrivate
  NetworkAclEntryInPublicAllowAll:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPublic
      RuleNumber: 99
      Protocol: -1
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: false
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  NetworkAclEntryOutPublicAllowAll:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPublic
      RuleNumber: 99
      Protocol: -1
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: true
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  NetworkAclEntryInPrivateAllowVpc:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPrivate
      RuleNumber: 99
      Protocol: -1
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: false
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  NetworkAclEntryOutPrivateAllowVpc:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref NetworkAclPrivate
      RuleNumber: 99
      Protocol: -1
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: true
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  LambdaSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Lambdas security group
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: '-1'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: '-1'
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Description: VPC ID
    Value: !Ref Vpc
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "Portal-VpcId"
  SubnetAPrivate:
    Description: Subnet A Private
    Value: !Ref SubnetAPrivate
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "SubnetAPrivate"
  SubnetBPrivate:
    Description: Subnet B Private
    Value: !Ref SubnetBPrivate
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "SubnetBPrivate"     
  SubnetAPublic:
    Description: Subnet A Public
    Value: !Ref SubnetAPublic
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "SubnetAPublic"
  SubnetBPublic:
    Description: Subnet B Public
    Value: !Ref SubnetBPublic
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "SubnetBPublic"  
  LambdaSecurityGroup:
    Description: Access to Lambda functions
    Value: !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "LambdaSecurityGroup"
```

rds.yml

```
DBSubnetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup'
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Subnets available for the RDS DB Instance
      SubnetIds: 
        - !Ref SubnetAPublic
        - !Ref SubnetBPublic
  VPCSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for RDS DB Instance.
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - 
          IpProtocol: "tcp"
          FromPort: "3306"
          ToPort: "3306"
          CidrIp: "[my IP]"
        - 
          IpProtocol: "tcp"
          FromPort: "3306"
          ToPort: "3306"
          CidrIp: "10.0.64.0/19"
        - 
          IpProtocol: "tcp"
          FromPort: "3306"
          ToPort: "3306"
          CidrIp: "10.0.96.0/19"
  DBInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBName: !Join
        - ''
        - - portal
          - !Ref Environment
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      Engine: MariaDB
      EngineVersion: '10.1.23'
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      StorageEncrypted: true
      PubliclyAccessible: true
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref VPCSecurityGroup
  DatabaseDnsRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Join 
        - ''
        - - !Ref HostedZoneName
          - .
      Name: !Join
      - ''
      - - portal
        - !Ref Environment
        - 'db'
        - .
        - !Ref HostedZoneName
        - .
      Type: CNAME
      TTL: '60'
      ResourceRecords: 
        - !GetAtt 
          - DBInstance
          - Endpoint.Address
    DependsOn: DBInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this

> The only thing that seems to work is if I switch all of the Route
>   Tables to use an IGW as opposed to a NAT

Your instances are located in private subnets which are not accessible from the public Internet (your home PC). You have three (or more) solutions:

1) Move your instances to a public subnet. NOT RECOMMENDED.

2) Convert your private subnet into a public subnet (switch from NAT to IGW). NOT RECOMMENDED.

3) Create a VPN from your home network to a new EC2 instance located in your public subnet that routes your traffic to the instances in the private subnet. **RECOMMENDED**.

OpenVPN is a very cool solution. You can build this yourself or just launch an OpenVPN instance from Amazon Marketplace for free (I think the free is limited to  2 users). [OpenVPN Access Server](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00MI40CAE?qid=1511819024502&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title)

There will be EC2 instance charges while the OpenVPN access server is running. What I do is shutdown that instance when I don't need it and start it back up when I do using the AWS CLI commands stored in batch files.